# How to get minimum and maximum value from List of Objects using Java 8

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

I have class like:

```
public class Test {
    private String Fname;
    private String Lname;
    private String Age;
    // getters, setters, constructor, toString, equals, hashCode, and so on
}
```

and a list like `List<Test> testList` filled with `Test` elements.

How can I get minimum and maximum value of `age` using Java 8?

Comment: I hate to sound like a broken record, but... `What have you tried? Show us some code and a specific error or problem.`

Comment: Since you specified, that you want to use Java 8, take a look at [`Streams`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html). You should be able to figure out the rest on your own.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To simplify things you should probably make your age `Integer` or `int` instead of Sting, but since your question is about `String age` this answer will be based on `String` type.

---

Assuming that `String age` holds String representing value in integer range you could simply map it to `IntStream` and use its `IntSummaryStatistics` like

```
IntSummaryStatistics summaryStatistics = testList.stream()
        .map(Test::getAge)
        .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
        .summaryStatistics();

int max = summaryStatistics.getMax();
int min = summaryStatistics.getMin();
```

Comment: No need for the double-map; just mapToInt(Test::getAge), the unboxing will be done for you.

Comment: @BrianGoetz Not quite. Notice that `getAge` returns `String` not `int`.

Comment: Who writes domain objects that store numbers in strings?  Sheesh. :)

Comment: OK, but returning to the domain of useful, the point I was trying to make was: lambda conversion will do necessary adaptation like widening, boxing, casting, etc, to make up differences between the natural type of the lambda and the target type -- that one need not manually insert adaptations like unboxing.

Answer (score 2):

max `age`:

```
   testList.stream()
            .mapToInt(Test::getAge)
            .max();
```

min `age`:

```
   testList.stream()
            .mapToInt(Test::getAge)
            .min();
```