# get List from with maximum and minimum sum from (nested List) List of List using Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, sum, java-stream, nested-lists

I was checking these question but it's not answer my question

[How to get minimum and maximum value from List of Objects using Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31083405/1410223)
[Find maximum, minimum, sum and average of a list in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25988707/1410223)

My problem I have nested List, and I want to obtain one List.

I have this class:

```
public class Competitor {
  private final int type;
  private final String name;
  private final int power;

  public Competitor(int type, String name, int power) {
    this.type = type;
    this.name = name;
    this.power = power;
  }

  public int getType() {
    return type;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public int getPower() {
    return power;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Competitor{" + "type=" + type + ", name=" + name + ", power=" + power + "} ";
  }

}
```

Now I have a `List<List<Competitor>>` like:

```
List<List<Competitor>> anotherListOfListCompetitor = new ArrayList<>();
anotherListOfListCompetitor.add(new ArrayList<>(
    Arrays.asList(new Competitor(1, "Cat 00", 93), new Competitor(2, "Dog 18", 40), new Competitor(3, "Pig 90", 90)))); //93 + 40 + 90 = 223

anotherListOfListCompetitor.add(new ArrayList<>(
    Arrays.asList(new Competitor(1, "Cat 23", 20), new Competitor(2, "Dog 30", 68), new Competitor(3, "Pig 78", 32)))); //20 + 68 + 32 = 120

anotherListOfListCompetitor.add(new ArrayList<>(
    Arrays.asList(new Competitor(1, "Cat 10", 11), new Competitor(4, "Cow 99", 90)))); //11 + 90 = 101
```

Now, I want to obtain the `List<Competitor>` with minimum sum of `power` Property and other `List<Competitor>` with maximum sum.

I know of reduce...

```
List<Competitor> someListCompetitor = //populate the list

int sumPower = someListCompetitor.stream()
    .map(competitor -> competitor.getPower())
    .reduce(0, (a, b) -> a + b);
```

**But is it possible for `List<List<Competitor>>` obtains the `minListCompetitor` with minimal `sumPower` and `anotherListCompetitor` with maximal `sumPower`?**

```
List<Competitor> minListCompetitor = anotherListOfListCompetitor
    .stream()... // which sum power is 101


List<Competitor> maxListCompetitor = anotherListOfListCompetitor
    .stream()... // which sum power is 223
```

**How obtain these lists?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
List<Competitor> minListCompetitor = anotherListOfListCompetitor.stream()
        .min(Comparator.comparingInt(l -> l.stream().mapToInt(Competitor::getPower).sum()))
        .orElse(Collections.emptyList());

List<Competitor> maxListCompetitor = anotherListOfListCompetitor.stream()
        .max(Comparator.comparingInt(l -> l.stream().mapToInt(Competitor::getPower).sum()))
        .orElse(Collections.emptyList());
```

This returns the `.min()` / `.max()` of the sum from the lists. It uses a simplified version of the code you provided to calculate the sum.

If you want to throw an exception if no maximum is found you can use `.orElseThrow()`.