# showing highest and lowest value of a series of objects in java

Tags: java

I have to find the highest scoring student  and the lowest scoring student from the given user input.but i only get the highest scoring student and can't get the lowest scoring student from it.

```
public class Student{

    public String name;
    public String id;
    public int score;
    public static int n;

    public Student(String initName,String initID,int initScore){

        initName=name;
        initID=id;
        initScore=score;
    }

    public Student (){

    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Enter the number of students:");
        Scanner s1=new Scanner(System.in);

      
        Student.n=Integer.parseInt(s1.nextLine().trim());

        System.out.println("Enter the student name,id and score.");
        Scanner s2=new Scanner(System.in);

        Student st1=new Student();
        Student min=new Student(" "," ",100);
        Student max=new Student(" "," ",0);
        for(int i=0;i<Student.n;i++){
            st1.name=s2.next();
            st1.id=s2.next();
            st1.score=s2.nextInt();

            if(max.score<st1.score){
                max.score=st1.score;
                max.name=st1.name;
                max.id=st1.id;
            }
            if(min.score>st1.score){
                min.name=st1.name;
                min.score=st1.score;
                min.id=st1.id;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("the highest scoring student: "+max.name);
        System.out.println("the lowest scoring student: "+min.name);
        
       
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not use nonsense characters to just add length to your text. The limits are there to force you to explain your problem and code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31083405/how-to-get-minimum-and-maximum-value-from-list-of-objects-using-java-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
        initScore=score;
```

Please fix the above line in constructor.

Actually all the assignments are incorrect:

```java
    public Student(String initName,String initID,int initScore){

        initName=name;
        initID=id;
        initScore=score;
    }
```

It should be changed to

```java
    public Student(String initName, String initId, int initScore) {
        name = initName;
        id = initId;
        score = initScore;
    }
```

Even better

```java
    public Student(String name, String id, int score) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.score = score;
    }
```

Since `score` is not assigned in the initial construction, it is assigned a default value of `0` and hence impacts the `min` computation. (as its already at min assuming the scores are positive)

It works for `max` computation as the scores obtained will be greater than or equal to `0` and will eventually update the `score` directly(assuming only positive scores are allowed).

Comment: tnx sorry didn't notice

Comment: Happy to have helped

Answer (score 0):

I see plenty of problems in your code and it seems you don't really know how to code, which makes me wanna recommend going through some `Java` tutorial first.

Now to your code:

- `Student` class implementation is just full of flaws, no encapsulation, mistakes in constructor, no idea what `n` is used for

  ```
  public class Student {

      private String name;
      private String id;
      private int score;

      public Student(String initName, String initID, int initScore){
          this.name = initName;
          this.id = initID;
          this.score = initScore;
      }

      // declare getters such as these two
      public String getName() {
          return this.name;
      }

      public int getScore() {
          return this.score;
      }
  }
  ```
- your `main` method has so many mistakes too: you have 2 `Scanners`, you don't initialize enough students and your iteration is plain wrong

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner s1 = new Scanner(System.in);
      // get number of students
      System.out.println("Enter the number of students:");
      int numberOfStudents = s1.nextInt();
      // initialize array of students
      Student[] array = new Student[numberOfStudents];
      for(int i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; i++) {
          // get name of the student
          System.out.println("Enter the student name:");
          String name = s1.nextLine();
          // get id of student
          System.out.println("Enter the student id:");
          String id = s1.nextLine();
          // get score of student
          System.out.println("Enter the student score:");
          int score = s1.nextInt();
          array[i] = new Student(name, id, score);
      }
      // now you have students input
      // it's time to find your student
      // set the lowest and highest student to first student
      Student min = array[0];
      Student max = array[0];
      for(int i = 1; i < numberOfStudents; i++) {
          if(min.getScore() > array[i]) {
              min = array[i];
          } else if(max.getScore() < array[i]) {
              max = array[i];
          }
      }
      System.out.println("the highest scoring student: "+max.getName());
      System.out.println("the lowest scoring student: "+min.getName());
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Carefully check the code again :

```
    public Student(String initName,String initID,int initScore){

    initName=name;
    initID=id;
    initScore=score;
}
```

Did you get it...? Buggy constructor.
The code should be

```
    public Student(String initName,String initID,int initScore){

    name = initName;
    id = initID;
    score = initScore;
}
```